# Why is this giving me the invalid base class error?

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I have two classes called Renderable and Triangle. The latter is supposed to be deriving from the former. I plan to be passing an array and its length into the Triangle constructor, which in turn will pass it to the constructor in the Renderable class that will handle the corresponding parameters. Here are the header files:

Renderable.h

```
class Renderable {
protected:
    const int dataLength = 0;
    const float* data[0] ;
public:
    Renderable();
    Renderable(int dataLength, float* data[]);
    virtual void render() const =0 ;
};
```

Triangle.h

```
#pragma once

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include "Renderable.h"

class Triangle : public Renderable {
public:

    void render() const;
};
```

So the problem is that the error check gave me `invalid base class`. I did some research and saw something about arrays' not being able to be an instance variable without specified size but this is still quite confusing to me. Could someone please enlighten me on this?

Also is there a more efficient solution to problems like this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the purpose of `data`? Why is it an array of size 0?

Comment: @cigien this is for OpenGl where I pass an array of floats into the gl state machine so that it renders things for me.

Comment: You've created here an array of `float*`'s of size 0. In order to have an array of floats, use `float* data;`

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenGI, but in C++ you can't have an array of size 0. You probably just want an array of floats, like `float *data;`

Comment: Even if a plain raw `float*` is wanted by OpenGL, I would still use e.g. `std::vector<float>` to store the data (or `std::array<float, N>` if the size is know compile-time).

Comment: I'm sorry, opengl doesn't actualy want an array of float pointers but an array of floats itself. I deleted all the  * symbols and it's still giving me the error.

Comment: Do you know how many floats you will have at compile time? If not you will need a dynamic array. You can't declare an array of 0 elements and expect to increase the number at runtime. It will always be 0.

Comment: I do know the number of floats I will have at compile time, but I plan to have different lengths of the data array for differrent implementations of the Renderable class. I want to reuse the initialization code from the Renderable class. Is this not desirable?

Comment: No, it's not desirable as currently written.  Specifying a float array size of zero will do nothing to help you achieve "different lengths for different implementations".  If you need it to be known at compile-time, you might consider making `Renderable` have no float array, and then derive a templated subclass that specifies `dataLength` in the template.  Then inherit from that for any subclasses that have fixed known arrays.  You can similarly subclass `Renderable` for an alternative branch of the hierarchy that provides variable-sized arrays (which could be implemented with `std::vector`).

Comment: Ah good idead, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> const float* data[0] ;
> ```

This array member declaration is ill-formed. The size of an array variable may not be 0.

Otherwise the example is well-formed (assuming the functions are defined in some translation unit).

> Also is there a more efficient solution to problems like this?

Solution is to not declare an array variable of size 0.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that the code design that I was going for is undesirable and I should either use `std::vector` or making another subtype of the `Renderable` class with a fixed array length and then extend from it.